# How to identify if this code for implementing webrtc is working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm currently working on a webrtc project that was written before from another developer.
While I'm currently new to webrtc and I tried hard to make it work after deleting obsolete functions and other things, now can I identify what is wrong here in my steps?

I'm following steps in [here](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections-advanced)

my code here is about trigger .call button

```
$(dod)
  .find(".call")
```

and I run throw signaling

```
wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
  data: { type: "login", id: id },
});
$(dod).hide(); 
//call*donecallProccess 1
setTimeout(() => {
  wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
    data: { type: "doneoif", id: id },
  });
}, 2e3);
```

that can trigger and process here

```
case "donecall":
    call(data.id);
    break;
    
  case "showcall":
    handleLogin(data.success, data.id);
    break;
  
  case "offercall":
    handleOffer(data.offer, data.name);
    break;
 
  case "answercall":
    handleAnswer(data.answer);
    break;
 
  case "candidatecall":
    handleCandidate(data.candidate);
    break;
  
  case "leavecall": 
    handleLeave();
```

then this code run one after each handle login and getUserMediaSuccess
gather permission from media stream and create a new RTCPeerConnection(servers)
get tracks from my streams with addtrack if I implement it correctly
and if ontrack happened can I collect streaming to add to remote peer like this way or should just add

```
yourConn.ontrack = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate !== null) {
       remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
      } else {
        console.log("there is an error with on trackevent", event);
      }
    };
```

complete code for previous handlelogin and call is

```
let handleLogin = async (success) => {
  try {
    if (success) {
      localVideo = document.getElementById("wbrtclocal");
      remoteVideo = document.getElementById("wbrtcremote");
      var getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia|| navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia ;

      if (getUserMedia) {
       getUserMedia({
            audio: { noiseSuppression: false },
          })
          .then(getUserMediaSuccess)
          .catch(errorHandler);
      } else {
        alert("Your browser does not support getUserMedia API");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Ooops...try a different username");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    errorHandler(error);
  }
};

let getUserMediaSuccess = async (streams) => {
  try {
    
    yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
    if(streams){
      localStream = streams;
      localVideo.srcObject = streams;
      streams.getTracks().forEach((track) => yourConn.addTrack(track, streams));
    }
   
    yourConn.onicecandidate = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate) {

        wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
          data: {
            type: "candidate",
            candidate: event.candidate,
            id: connectedUser,
          },
        });

      }
      console.log("nwe ice candidate is", event.candidate);
      console.log("nwe stream is", streams);
    };

     remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;


    yourConn.ontrack = (event) => {
      if (event.candidate !== null) {
        event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track) => {
          remoteStream.addTrack(track);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("there is an error with on trackevent", event);
      }
    };
  } catch (err) {
    errorHandler(error);
  }
  console.log("stream is", streams);
};
```

call function

```
async function call(id) {
  $("#videoCall").show();
  if (id.length > 0) {
    connectedUser = id;

    try {

     RTCPeerConnection.createOffer().
    offer.
      await yourConn
        .createOffer()
        .then((offer) => successCallback)
        .catch((e) => {
          fl(e);
        });
      let successCallback = async (offer) => {
        try {
     
         
          yourConn
            .setLocalDescription(offer)
            .then(
             
              wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
                data: { type: "offer", offer: offer, id: connectedUser },
              })
            )
            .catch((e) => {
              fl(e);
            });
        } catch (e) {
          fl(e);
        }
      };
    } catch (e) {
      fl(e);
    }

    const user = U_CASH[id];
    if (user) {
      $("#videoCall")
        .find(".u-pic")
        .css("background-image", "url(" + removegifpic(user.pic + ")"));
      $("#videoCall").find(".u-topic").text(user.topic);
    }
    $(".statecall").text("جاري الإتصال");
    hl($(".statecall"), "warning");
  } else {
    alert("username can't be blank!");
  }
  console.log("connectedUser", id);
  console.log("offer", offer);
  console.log();
  console.log();
  console.log();
}


and this about each one for those 
[handleOffer , handleAnswer , handleCandidate , handleLeave]

let handleOffer = async (offer, name) => {
  $("#callvideonot").show();
  const user = U_CASH[name];
  if (user) {
    $("#callvideonot")
    .find(".u-pic")
    .css("background-image", "url(" + removegifpic(user.pic + ")"));
    $("#callvideonot").find(".u-topic").text(user.topic);
  }
 
  $(".callvideoaccept").on("click", async () => {
    connectedUser = name;
    

    await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(offer);


 
    yourConn
      .createAnswer()
      .then((answer) => t.setLocalDescription(answer))
      .then(() => {
        wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
          data: { type: "answer", answer: answer, id: connectedUser },
        });
      })
      .catch(fl);

    
    const user = U_CASH[name];
    if (user) {
      $(".statecall").text("متصل");
      hl($(".statecall"), "success");
      $("#videoCall")
        .find(".u-pic")
        .css("background-image", "url(" + removegifpic(user.pic + ")"));
      $("#videoCall").find(".u-topic").text(user.topic);
    }
    $("#callvideonot").hide();
    $("#videoCall").show();
  });


   
  $(".callvideodeny").on("click", function () {
    wbsc.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_CALL_AUDIO", {
      data: { type: "leave", id: name },
    });
  });
};


   
let handleAnswer = async (answer) => {
  try {
    $(".statecall").text("متصل");
    hl($(".statecall"), "success");
    //here we delete new RTCSessionDescription because constructor is deprecated.
   await yourConn.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  } catch (e) {
    fl(e);
  }
};

let handleCandidate = async (candidate) => {
  try {
      
    var NewlyIceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)
    .setRemoteDescription().
    await yourConn.addIceCandidate(NewlyIceCandidate);
   
  } catch (e) {
    fl(e);
  }
};
   
function handleLeave() {
  $("#callvideonot").hide();
  $(".statecall").text("رفض");
  hl($(".statecall"), "danger");
  $(".vloumemic").removeClass("fa-volume-off");
  $(".vloumemic").addClass("fa-volume-up");
  $(".mutemic").removeClass("fa-microphone-slash");
  $(".mutemic").addClass("fa-microphone");
  setTimeout(() => {
    $("#videoCall").hide();
  }, 1e3);
  if (localStream) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach((e) => e.stop());
  }
  if (connectedUser) {
    connectedUser = null;
  }
  remoteVideo.src = null;
  if (yourConn) {
    yourConn.close();
    yourConn.onicecandidate = null;
    yourConn.ontrack = null;
    localStream = null;
  }
}
```

in here [here](https://webrtc.org/getting-started/peer-connections-advanced) number 7 instruction they said should I add Wait for an incoming remote SDP description from the signaling service and set it using RTCPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(). as the caller where can I add it? in handleCandidate function?

and in the callee side number 1 instruction the said that I should
Create a new RTCPeerConnection instance with the appropriate ICE configuration.

can I reuse

```
yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

or should instantiate a new one to prevent conflict in website server process
as a not yourConn it's global value and in top level of this file and reuse it over all
the connection, is peers 2 or the callee should have another new RTCPeerConnection?

and for `remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;` the remoteStream value is global and I overwrite it. can I here add new media stream or just it's good to dealing with the present one which is remoteVideo element?

```
 // remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue that was here is to split the RTCPeerConnection object and just create new one for each peer local and remote  that what i did and it working corectly after i remove addtrack completly and replace it with addtranceiver and gettranceiver
u can find it here from previous issue's answer and i fix it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74642498/what-is-the-appropriate-way-to-achieve-offer-to-recieve-and-send-in-webrtc)

and  no need to overwrite or reset the srcObect value. The track transition on receiver side in the same MediaStream should be "seamless" [RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5700232381726720)
This allows you to seamlessly change which track is being sent without having to renegotiate at the expense of another offer/answer cycle